# Windows management

Tags: macos, windows, dock, window-manager

Just wondering whether its possible to achieve my goal.

Imagine you are running Firefox and have all windows minimized to Dock.

If you switch to other application and back to Firefox via `cmd+Tab`, it would open last minimized window (this is what I want to prevent).

So is it possible to force Firefox (and any application) to show only Main Menu Item after `cmd+Tab` if all windows are minimized?

Actually I am talking about global OS X option and window management, Firefox mentioned just as an example of multi-window environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current option to accomplish the said goal. I understand the frustration. OS X isn't doing exactly great on windows management, partly because Microsoft has patterns on certain operation design.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

there is a setting in FF for that.

[image: open FF window]

> Don't load tabs until selected.

I have not found anything doing exactly what you asked on system wide level but ere are some alternative solutions.

[Keyboard shortcut for restoring applications from the Mac OS X Dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55432/46541)

[What are the differences between minimizing and hiding an application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9048/46541)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7681418/2241562

Comment: Actually I was talking about global OS X option and window management, Firefox mentioned just as an example of multi-window environment

Comment: @Buscar웃 He might have Word open with multiple documents minimized to dock. He might have the mail app open with the main window and multiple emails (opened by double clicking the email in the main window) minimized to dock. He might have Steam open with the main window, a chat window, a friends list, and a game minimized to dock. There are many more examples...